# How to succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, glm, lm

Suppose I have a response variable and a data containing three covariates (as a toy example):

```
y = c(1,4,6)
d = data.frame(x1 = c(4,-1,3), x2 = c(3,9,8), x3 = c(4,-4,-2))
```

I want to fit a linear regression to the data:

```
fit = lm(y ~ d$x1 + d$x2 + d$y2)
```

Is there a way to write the formula, so that I don't have to write out each individual covariate? For example, something like

```
fit = lm(y ~ d)
```

(I want each variable in the data frame to be a covariate.) I'm asking because I actually have 50 variables in my data frame, so I want to avoid writing out `x1 + x2 + x3 + etc`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Specifying formula in R with glm without explicit declaration of each covariate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588961/specifying-formula-in-r-with-glm-without-explicit-declaration-of-each-covariate)

Comment: Also see [how to insert dataframe column name into equation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25954361/how-to-insert-dataframe-column-name-into-equation-r).

Answer (score 263, accepted):

There is a special identifier that one can use in a formula to mean all the variables, it is the `.` identifier.

```
y <- c(1,4,6)
d <- data.frame(y = y, x1 = c(4,-1,3), x2 = c(3,9,8), x3 = c(4,-4,-2))
mod <- lm(y ~ ., data = d)
```

You can also do things like this, to use all variables but one (in this case x3 is excluded):

```
mod <- lm(y ~ . - x3, data = d)
```

Technically, `.` means *all variables **not** already mentioned in the formula*. For example

```
lm(y ~ x1 * x2 + ., data = d)
```

where `.` would only reference `x3` as `x1` and `x2` are already in the formula.

Comment: The data frame 'd' has 4 columns (y, x1, x2, and x3). So if the formula is "y ~ .", does the right hand side mean "all the columns" except those listed on the left hand side?

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010 Yes, `.` technically means all variables in `data` *not already in the formula*.

Comment: @theforestecologist if you mean `data` is a list from which variables in the formula are looked up from that list, then yes. A data frame, list or environment are acceptable options for the `data` argument. If that's not what you mean, you'll need to expand a little more.

Comment: @Gavin. That is what I meant. Thanks. How would I go about this method using data[[x]] as a listed variable vs. the actual variable name (e.g, 'x3')? For example, how would I make the following work?: `lm(d[[1]] ~ d[[3]] + ., data = d)`

Comment: It works off the `names` of the list; say you have `ll <- list(y = rnorm(10), x = rnorm(10), z = rnorm(10), zz = runif(10))`, then the following works: `lm(y ~ x + ., data = ll)`. So there isn't much reason to have your data like this unless it already is a list, but it works. The requirement that the elements of the formula be the same length puts some restrictions on what you have in a list. More complex objects probably need code to extract the elements you want; if `d[[1]]` were a data frame/matrix you need code to make that work

Comment: For more info, see `?formula`.

Answer (score 79):

A slightly different approach is to create your formula from a string. In the `formula` help page you will find the following example :

```
## Create a formula for a model with a large number of variables:
xnam <- paste("x", 1:25, sep="")
fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))
```

Then if you look at the generated formula, you will get :

```
R> fmla
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + 
    x12 + x13 + x14 + x15 + x16 + x17 + x18 + x19 + x20 + x21 + 
    x22 + x23 + x24 + x25
```

Comment: This works very well for reading these values from a file. Thanks!

Comment: Note that the as.formula part is a mustt

Answer (score 11):

Yes of course, just add the response `y` as first column in the dataframe and call `lm()` on it:

```
d2<-data.frame(y,d)
> d2
  y x1 x2 x3
1 1  4  3  4
2 4 -1  9 -4
3 6  3  8 -2
> lm(d2)

Call:
lm(formula = d2)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
    -5.6316       0.7895       1.1579           NA
```

Also, my information about R points out that assignment with `<-` is recommended over `=`.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I know everyone always says to use <-, but nobody ever says why and = is easier to type =).

Comment: @gratur One reason is that things like `foo(bar <- 1:10)` work (and `bar` is created) but `foo(bar = 1:10)` would either fail because `bar` is not an argument of `foo` and won't create `bar` either.

Comment: Why is the coefficient of `x3` `NA`?

Comment: @Ziyuan: Because we are trying to estimate 4 parameters (including intercept) with just 3 data points. The system is indeterminate and lm solves it by dropping one variable.

Answer (score 10):

An extension of juba's method is to use `reformulate`, a function which is explicitly designed for such a task.

```
## Create a formula for a model with a large number of variables:
xnam <- paste("x", 1:25, sep="")

reformulate(xnam, "y")
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + x6 + x7 + x8 + x9 + x10 + x11 + 
    x12 + x13 + x14 + x15 + x16 + x17 + x18 + x19 + x20 + x21 + 
    x22 + x23 + x24 + x25
```

For the example in the OP, the easiest solution here would be

```
# add y variable to data.frame d
d <- cbind(y, d)
reformulate(names(d)[-1], names(d[1]))
y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
```

or

```
mod <- lm(reformulate(names(d)[-1], names(d[1])), data=d)
```

Note that adding the dependent variable to the data.frame in `d <- cbind(y, d)` is preferred not only because it allows for the use of `reformulate`, but also because it allows for future use of the `lm` object in functions like `predict`.

Answer (score 2):

I build this solution, `reformulate` does not take care if variable names have white spaces.

```
add_backticks = function(x) {
    paste0("`", x, "`")
}

x_lm_formula = function(x) {
    paste(add_backticks(x), collapse = " + ")
}

build_lm_formula = function(x, y){
    if (length(y)>1){
        stop("y needs to be just one variable")
    }
    as.formula(        
        paste0("`",y,"`", " ~ ", x_lm_formula(x))
    )
}

# Example
df <- data.frame(
    y = c(1,4,6), 
    x1 = c(4,-1,3), 
    x2 = c(3,9,8), 
    x3 = c(4,-4,-2)
    )

# Model Specification
columns = colnames(df)
y_cols = columns[1]
x_cols = columns[2:length(columns)]
formula = build_lm_formula(x_cols, y_cols)
formula
# output
# "`y` ~ `x1` + `x2` + `x3`"

# Run Model
lm(formula = formula, data = df)
# output
Call:
    lm(formula = formula, data = df)

Coefficients:
    (Intercept)           x1           x2           x3  
        -5.6316       0.7895       1.1579           NA
```

```

Answer (score 0):

You can check the package `leaps` and in particular the function `regsubsets()`
functions for model selection. As stated in the documentation:

*Model selection by exhaustive search, forward or backward stepwise, or sequential replacement*