# How to pass data frame columns into a column vector to be used on RHS of regression model?

Tags: r, formula, names

I have a list of 100 columns in a data frame Data1. One of these variables is the dependent variable. The others are predictors.

I need to extract 99 predictors into a column (say `varlist`) to be used in the equation below

```
equation <- as.formula(paste('y', "~", paste(varlist, collapse="+"),collapse=""))
```

I can use `dput` on the dataframe to extract all the columns but I could not get rid of the dependent variable y from the list:

```
Varlist <- dput(names(Data1))
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame)

Answer (score 7):

It would be much more appropriate to go a different route.  If you want to include all of the other variables in your data frame besides the response variable you can just use `y ~ .` to specify that.

```
fakedata <- as.data.frame(matrix(rnorm(100000), ncol = 100))
names(fakedata)[1] <- "y"

o <- lm(y ~ ., data = fakedata)
```

This fit a regression using the 99 other columns in fakedata as the predictors and 'y' as the response and stored it into 'o'

---

Edit:  If you want to exclude some variables you can exclude those from the data set.  The following removes the 10th column through the 100th column leaving a regression of y on columns 2-9

```
o <- lm(y ~ ., data = fakedata[,-(10:100)])
```

Comment: But what if there a could be other vaiables I might want to exclude as well.

Comment: You can remove those column from the data first.  I made an edit to illustrate.