# How to exclude some variables from dot in formula when used with aggregate() in R, i.e. all but some?

Tags: r

I have quite many variables to feed like to `aggregate` and apparently I'm lazy to explicitly type all especially they change once in a while but those I'd like to exclude are mostly the same. I tried to write

```
hru.mean <-
    aggregate(.-LULC~GIS, hru.annual, "mean")
```

but apparently it is not quite right as it says

```
Error in aggregate.data.frame(mf[1L], mf[-1L], FUN = FUN, ...) : 
  no rows to aggregate
In addition: Warning message:
In Ops.factor(., LULC) : - not meaningful for factors
```

I just saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5251676/673826), so it looks like it works for `lm` but does not work for `aggregate`. Are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this where you limit the columns in the data set instead:

```
aggregate(.~cyl, mtcars[, !colnames(mtcars) %in% c("hp")], mean)
```

Comment: I realized that I can also feed something like `subset(hru.annual, select=-c(LULC, HRU))`. Perhaps it is a separate question but nevertheless... I have a gut feeling that `subset` generally is neater. Though I don't know internals.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just pass a subset as the data

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, data = iris, mean)
```

compared with

```
aggregate(. ~ Species, iris[,-which(names(iris) == 'Sepal.Length')], mean)
```

Comment: Subsetting will definitely work. I was not sure whether I was doing something wrong with formula. I guess there could be a better support in aggregate() for that.