# How to insert dataframe column name into equation R?

Tags: r, variables

I am trying to make a section of code more flexible by referencing the data frame column names and inserting them into an equation, rather than calling the names directly.  The following example works, although I have to insert the field name directly:

```
require(e1071)

class = c(0.25, 0.34, 0.55)
field1 = c(23, 33, 34)
field2 = c(44, 55, 32)

df = data.frame(class, field1, field2)

mysvm = svm(class ~ field1 + field2, data = df)
```

The following example *does not* work, and I do not know why:

```
require(e1071)

class = c(0.25, 0.34, 0.55)
field1 = c(23, 33, 34)
field2 = c(44, 55, 32)

df = data.frame(class, field1, field2)

name1 = names(df)[2]
name2 = names(df)[3]

mysvm = svm(class ~ name1 + name2, data = df)
```

How can I reference the 2nd and 3rd columns in a dataframe and properly insert them into an equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable `name1` contains a character string that is equal to `names(df)[2]`, let's say it's `"foo"`. When `svm` receives a `formula` object with the term `name1`, it searches for an object named `name1` and replaces that object with its value. That is, `svm` is trying to "regress" the variable `class` on the length-one character vector `"foo"`, which of course doesn't make sense.

One workaround here is to create the formula as a character string, and then convert it to a formula after the fact. Here's a utility function I use from time to time:

```
xyform <- function (y_var, x_vars) {
# y_var: a length-one character vector
# x_vars: a character vector of object names
    as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ %s", y_var, paste(x_vars, collapse = " + ")))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if you care how the formula reads in the call output, but to evaluate it you can do

```
> foo <- function(n1, n2) {
      as.formula(paste("class~", paste(n1, n2, sep = "+")))
  }
> foo(name1, name2)
# class ~ field1 + field2
# <environment: 0x4d0da58>
> svm(foo(name1, name2), data = df)
#
# Call:
# svm(formula = foo(name1, name2), data = df)
#
#    
# Parameters:
#    SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
#  SVM-Kernel:  radial 
#        cost:  1 
#       gamma:  0.5 
#     epsilon:  0.1 
#
# Number of Support Vectors:  3
```

Answer (score 2):

Here 2 options:

Either you subset your data.frame, by the column names given as a parameter and you use the `dot` notation for the left term of your formula:

```
svm_func <- function(ll=c("field1","field1"),xx=df){
  print(df[,c("class",ll)])
  svm(class ~ ., data = df[,c("class",ll)])
}
```

Or you use the forumla version of svm , similar to other solutions but here I am using `do.call` to generalize formula creation to a any number of parameter:

```
svm_func_form <- function(ll=list("field1","field1"),xx=df){
  left_term <- do.call(paste,list(ll,collapse="+"))
  form <- as.formula(paste("class",left_term,sep="~"))
  svm(formula =form,data =xx)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some ways to pass variables by reference and insert it into `Call` formula.  The first line is copied from @Richard Scriven's function

```
 fun1 <- function(n1, n2){
 form1 <- as.formula(paste("class~", paste(n1, n2, sep = "+")))
 do.call("svm", list(form1, quote(df)))
 }    

 fun1(name1, name2)

 #Call:
 #svm(formula = class ~ field1 + field2, data = df)


 #Parameters:
 # SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 # SVM-Kernel:  radial 
 #  cost:  1 
 # gamma:  0.5 
 # epsilon:  0.1 


 #Number of Support Vectors:  3
```

Or

```
 fun2 <- function(n1, n2){
 form1 <- as.formula(paste("class~", paste(n1, n2, sep="+")))
 eval(substitute(svm(f, df), list(f = form1)))
 }  

 fun2(name1, name2)

 #Call:
 #svm(formula = class ~ field1 + field2, data = df)


 #Parameters:
 # SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 # SVM-Kernel:  radial 
 #  cost:  1 
 # gamma:  0.5 
 #  epsilon:  0.1 


 #Number of Support Vectors:  3
```

Or   you could pass @Rchard Scriven's function as an argument in `fun3`

```
 fun2New <- function(n1, n2){
  as.formula(paste("class~", paste(n1, n2, sep="+")))
  }



 fun3 <- function(formula, data, ...){
 Call <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
 Call[[1]] <- as.name("svm")
 Call$formula <- as.formula(terms(formula))
 eval(Call)
 }

 fun3(fun2New(name1, name2), df)

 #Call:
 #svm(formula = class ~ field1 + field2, data = df)


 #Parameters:
 # SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 # SVM-Kernel:  radial 
 #  cost:  1 
 # gamma:  0.5 
 # epsilon:  0.1 


 #Number of Support Vectors:  3
```

Comment: How is `fun2New` any different from my function `foo`?

Comment: @Richard Scriven I used `fun2New` as an argument for `fun3` to change the formula in `Call` statement.  I should have put that function inside `fun3`.  But, somehow not getting it correct. Anyway, the OP seems to not want that kind of function.  So, I am not working on it.

Comment: But did you copy it from Richard's answer without attribution?

Comment: @Matthew Lundberg I edited it. Sorry, I didn't thought about it at that time.  Is it okay now?

Answer (score 1):

Use your own code, just use get(name1) instead of name1 !

```
> mysvm = svm(class ~ get(name1) + get(name2), data = df)
> mysvm

Call:
svm(formula = class ~ get(name1) + get(name2), data = df)


Parameters:
   SVM-Type:  eps-regression 
 SVM-Kernel:  radial 
       cost:  1 
      gamma:  0.5 
    epsilon:  0.1 


Number of Support Vectors:  3
```