# Predicting LDA testing set different legnth than testing set

Tags: r, cross-validation

I'm having issues predicting in lda. I want to cross validate my set, so I split my data into a training set (80%) and a testing set (20%) 5 times. This gives me two dataframes of different length. I can make the training lda no problem, but when I predict I don't get the newdata prediction. It goes automatically to the training set predictions. Any help for a R newbie?

```
 df.test=structure(list(DEV.rabbit.Bi = c(0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L,0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L,0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L), cytoP = c(0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.1260048, 0, 0, 0, 2.83428136, 0, 0, NA,0, -2.33067135, -3.2528685, 0, 0, -3.9118235, 0, -2.12893162,0, -2.135834975, -3.38015, 0, 2.86341288, 0, -2.4050405, 0, -2.38829672,0, -2.24985834, 0, -2.2202064, -2.15253385, -2.2366473, -2.96851445,0, -0.743292433, 0, 0, 0, -2.61448215, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.9443965,0, 0), GIP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.88683115, 0, 0, 0, 4.31335206, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.900614, 0, 1.4537355, 0,6.168443, 3.872625, 3.1133642, 0, 2.3501405), neuroP = c(0, 0,2.0428646, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.165785, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0,0, 0, 2.5078381, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.317407, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 1.9766362, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.6628686, 0, 0, 0, 4.6432279,4.586727, 0, 0, 0, 7.039145), ProlifP = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 3.562687467, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,-2.12833253, 4.947180667, -2.04286463, 0, 0, 0, -2.562395, 0,0, 0, -2.346905, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.005820067, -3.0411488, -1.885536,-3.2384957, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.6344196, 0, -4.767982), reproP = c(0.018018017,0.418918933, 0.040540533, 0.018018017, 0.454954967, 0, 0, 0.049549533,0, 0, 0, 0.3963964, 0.058558567, 0.040540533, NA, 0.054054067,0.441441433, 0, 0, 0.040540533, 0.063063067, 0, 0.35135135, 0.058558567,0.018018017, 0, 0.027027027, 0.040540533, 0.1036036, 0.4, 0.2,0.018018017, 0.130630633, 0.018018017, 0.1, 0.054054067, 0.031531533,0.081081067, 0.1036036, 0.040540533, 0.0900901, 0.369369367,0.036036033, -1.1009885, -0.673395133, NA, 0.045045033, 0, 0,0.1036036, -0.984343, 0)), .Names = c("DEV.rabbit.Bi", "cytoP","GIP", "neuroP", "ProlifP", "reproP"), row.names = c(12L, 23L,24L, 27L, 38L, 56L, 59L, 61L, 63L, 65L, 71L, 81L, 128L, 131L,141L, 154L, 163L, 168L, 170L, 184L, 186L, 205L, 210L, 217L, 233L,236L, 253L, 268L, 276L, 293L, 302L, 303L, 312L, 314L, 322L, 326L,335L, 339L, 343L, 361L, 377L, 385L, 392L, 394L, 399L, 402L, 418L,419L, 422L, 427L, 438L, 453L), class = "data.frame")
df.train= structure(list(DEV.rabbit.Bi = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L,0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L,1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L,1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L,0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L,0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L,0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L,0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L,1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), cytoP = c(0,NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,NA, 0, 0, 0, -2.648429, 0, 0, -2.1260048, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,2.83428136, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, -3.126005, 0, 0,0, 7.0318728, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 3.024976, 0,0, 0, -2.33067135, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, -3.3048862, 3.2453672, 0,NA, 0, -3.9118235, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3.3074869, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, NA, 0, 0, 0, -3.64705195, 0, 0, -2.6801575, 0, -2.32687549,0, 0, -3.38015, 0, 0, NA, 0, -2.4122793, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.434712735,2.86341288, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3.73306513, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, -2.38829672, 0, 0, 0, -0.823873667, 0, 0, 0, -2.24985834,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.2202064, 0, -2.34696895, NA, NA, 0, -2.15253385,-2.1856675, -2.2366473, 2.017460955, -2.96851445, 0, 0, 0, -3.0842214,0, -3.50124325, -5.794065, 0, NA, 0, -3.1539793, -2.5736979,0, 0, -2.3865695, 0, -2.710736745, 0, -0.743292433, 0, 2.373366367,0, -2.75693455, NA, NA, -2.61448215, NA, 0, 0, 0, -2.2124975,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -3.053354, NA, 5.428529647, -2.9443965,-3.8878643, -2.2083998, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, -2.13583495, 0, 0,0), GIP = c(0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,5.820918, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.73598124, 0, 0,4.588133, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.0566821, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 4.31335206, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8.6651012, 0, 2.55087375,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.068526045, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 6.3948068, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.3290915, 3.205779325, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 1.01417725, 0, 0, 1.35015685, 0, 0, NA, 1.290875, 0,NA, 1.4537355, 0, 0, 0, 3.1133642, 0, 0, 0, 6.168443, 0, 6.26968469,3.872625, 0, 3.890076867, 0, 3.1133642, 2.250768067, 0, 0.97301535,4.8966569, 0, 8.487644, 0, 3.798781, 3.253654875, 4.960366, 0,2.3501405), neuroP = c(0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.0428646, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 11.03703, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 5.165785, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.583922, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.0009107, 0, NA,NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.55936099, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA,2.5078381, 0, NA, 0, 3.872625, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.97424399,0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.5064081, NA,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.16196, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1.929947, 0, 2.000911, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 2.247053, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 1.9766362, 2.126448,0, 0, 0, 0, 4.130221, 0, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,2.599616, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.0913634,0, 0, 4.6432279, 4.586727, 0, 1.58651903, 0, 2.6652475, NA, 0,0, 0, 3.5208109, 4.2195317, 0, 0, NA, 10.5157265, NA, 0, 0, 2.8920614,7.039145), ProlifP = c(0, NA, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1.945246, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, NA, 0, -11.05227, 0, 0, 0,0, 3.562687467, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, -2.02585, 3.887923007, NA,0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3.7865502, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.947180667, 0, 0, NA, 0, 0, 0, 0,-2.04286463, -2.0343177, 0, 0, 5.591507567, 0, -2.0868461, 0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5.151728643, 4.936735813, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.562395,0, -2.009148, -7.564251, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -2.346905,3.207918667, 0, 0, -2.9254072, NA, NA, 0, 0, -2.5948795, 0, -2.060203,0, -4.14739583, -2.8027302, -4.487039, 0, 0, 0, NA, -2.8964375,5.003374, -2.263317, 0, 3.609647733, -2.6806902, 0, 3.505242133,0, 3.120921753, -3.445611, 0, 0, 5.147579867, 0, 0, NA, NA, -3.2384957,NA, 0, 0, 0, -2.798781, -1.6022584, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4.713909533,4.4782686, -5.831885, 5.6344196, -6.8794451, 4.888960867, -3.1387679,-5.5994579, 0, NA, 0, NA, 0, 0, -4.6923589, -4.767982), reproP = c(0,0.58783785, 0.1486486, 0, 0.018018017, 0, 0.063063067, 0.418918933,0.040540533, 0, 0.4864865, 0.018018017, 0.0855856, 0.018018017,0.3963964, 0, 0, 0.0990991, 0.333333333, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.076576567,0, 0.081081067, 0.049549533, 0.3873874, 0, 0, 0, 0.15, 0.06756755,0.0617284, 0.3963964, 0.383333333, 0.018018017, 0, 0.15, 0.031531533,0.3918919, 0.058558567, 0.0810811, 0, 0, 0.067567567, 0, 0, 0,0, 0, 0.06756755, 0, 0.516666667, NA, 0.058558567, 0.1621622,0.2567568, NA, NA, 0.1419753, 0, 0, 0.054054067, 0.040540533,0.018018017, 0.441441433, 0.031531533, 0, 0, 0, 0.1126126, 0.072072067,0, 0.35802469, 0.0472973, 0.040540533, 0.063063067, 0.16216215,0.083333333, 0.333333333, 0.018018017, 0.024691357, 0.0945946,0.0945946, 0.045045033, 0, 0.037037035, 0, 0.081081067, 0, 0.135135133,0.058558567, 0.081081067, 0.031531533, 0, 0.013513513, 0.063063067,0.333333333, 0.35802469, 0.1081081, 0.040540533, 0, 0.018018017,0.081081067, 0.075, 0.045045033, 0.067567567, 0.040540533, 0.031531533,0.027027027, 0.031531533, 0.036036033, 0.45, 0.018018017, 0.040540533,-0.7265556, 0.031531533, 0.4144144, 0.10185185, 0.067567567,0, 0.040540533, 0.018018017, 0.027027025, 0.0990991, 0.1036036,0.027027025, 0.054054067, 0.2, 0.018018017, 0, 0, 0.033333333,0, 0.031531533, 0.378378367, 0.130630633, 0.018018017, 0.1, 0,0, 0.1, 0, 0.054054067, 0.459459467, 0.031531533, 0.075, 0.5,0.364864867, 0.031531533, 0.06756755, 0.081081067, 0.6418919,0.1036036, 0.35135135, 0.054054067, -0.931616333, 0.3918919,0, 0.0855856, 0.1081081, 0.373873867, NA, 0.333333333, 0.0990991,-1.345913467, 0.040540533, 0.018018017, 0.081081067, 0.3963964,0.018018017, 0, 0.0900901, 0.2027027, 0.031531533, 0.3963964,0.364864867, 0.0743243, 0, -0.673395133, 0.06756755, NA, -0.316663167,0.031531533, 0, 0.031531533, 0.3873874, 0.0608108, 0.045045033,0, -1.004574, 0.018018017, 0, 0.4144144, 0.55405405, 0, 0.1036036,-1.646125933, -1.5806603, -0.9572768, -0.818359433, -0.984343,0.2, -4.2037963, 0, -1.2499105, 0.4, 0.0608108, 0)), .Names = c("DEV.rabbit.Bi","cytoP", "GIP", "neuroP", "ProlifP", "reproP"), row.names = c(2L,4L, 6L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 15L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L,30L, 34L, 35L, 39L, 40L, 43L, 44L, 48L, 55L, 56L, 57L, 58L, 59L,60L, 61L, 62L, 63L, 65L, 71L, 72L, 75L, 79L, 81L, 84L, 85L, 86L,87L, 91L, 92L, 93L, 94L, 97L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 105L, 112L, 115L,118L, 119L, 120L, 121L, 126L, 128L, 129L, 132L, 136L, 141L, 144L,148L, 151L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 163L, 164L, 166L, 169L, 170L, 178L,179L, 180L, 181L, 183L, 184L, 186L, 188L, 190L, 191L, 193L, 194L,198L, 199L, 200L, 201L, 202L, 205L, 206L, 212L, 215L, 217L, 222L,223L, 224L, 228L, 229L, 230L, 231L, 232L, 235L, 236L, 238L, 239L,244L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 252L, 253L, 257L, 262L, 263L, 265L, 268L,271L, 272L, 275L, 279L, 282L, 285L, 286L, 287L, 289L, 290L, 291L,294L, 301L, 302L, 303L, 304L, 305L, 307L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L,314L, 315L, 317L, 319L, 322L, 323L, 326L, 327L, 329L, 331L, 333L,334L, 335L, 338L, 339L, 342L, 343L, 344L, 346L, 349L, 350L, 352L,353L, 354L, 356L, 359L, 360L, 363L, 365L, 366L, 368L, 370L, 371L,374L, 376L, 377L, 380L, 381L, 384L, 387L, 393L, 395L, 399L, 400L,402L, 403L, 408L, 409L, 414L, 415L, 417L, 418L, 419L, 420L, 421L,422L, 424L, 425L, 426L, 427L, 428L, 429L, 434L, 437L, 438L, 441L,442L, 443L, 444L, 448L, 451L, 453L), class = "data.frame")

lda.train= lda(df.train$DEV.rabbitBi~ df.train[,c(2)] +df.train[,c(3)]+df.train[,c(4)]+df.train[,c(5)]+df.train[,c(6)], data=df.train)

lda.pred= predict(lda.train, newdata=df.test)$class
```

Comment: I think this will likely be to how you are passing the variables to `lda`. As you are not using the variable names, then `predict` cannot match the variables in the `newdata` to the fitted model. [ps i think `df.train` dput is incomplete]

Comment: Would it be able to predict my data if it were a different format or if I attached the names?

Comment: Try fitting the `lda` with `lda.train <- lda(DEV.rabbitBi~ ., data=df.train[c(1:6)])` and then predicting

Comment: It worked! Do you mind explaining the syntax of what that means/ does and put it in an answer (esp the "~.," because I don't know what that means). I'm trying to understand R grammar and also want to give you credit for answering my question!

Comment: good stuff, ill write up in a wee bit. cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The call to predict does not work as the variable names that are in the `lda` model output
do not match the variable names in the newdata / test data. (see the `newdata` argument description 
in `?predict.lda` ...  *a data frame with columns of the same names as the variables used*).
As they don't match, the predict method ignores the `newdata` argument and predicts on the original data. 
You have used the same variables in the model and in the predict 
but it matters how they are passed to the lda model.

Using the example from `?lda`

```
library(MASS)

Iris <- data.frame(rbind(iris3[,,1], iris3[,,2], iris3[,,3]),
                   Sp = rep(c("s","c","v"), rep(50,3)))
train <- sample(1:150, 75)

names(Iris)
#[1] "Sepal.L." "Sepal.W." "Petal.L." "Petal.W." "Sp"      

z <- lda(Sp ~ . , Iris, prior = c(1,1,1)/3, subset = train)
z
#...
#...
# Coefficients of linear discriminants:
#                 LD1        LD2
# Sepal.L.  0.5863648  0.7580133
# Sepal.W.  2.0444073 -2.5613102
# Petal.L. -1.8827963  0.9356446
# Petal.W. -3.5895106 -3.4927051
#...
#...
```

Variable names in the model match those found in the data, and match those in the `newdata`, so `predict` will work as intended

```
pred <- predict(z, Iris[-train, ])
```

When you pass the variables differently you can run into problems.

```
z <- lda(Sp ~ Iris[,1] + Iris[,2] + Iris[,3] + Iris[,4]  , Iris, prior = c(1,1,1)/3, subset = train)
z
# Coefficients of linear discriminants:
#                  LD1        LD2
# Iris[, 1]  0.5863648  0.7580133
# Iris[, 2]  2.0444073 -2.5613102
# Iris[, 3] -1.8827963  0.9356446
# Iris[, 4] -3.5895106 -3.4927051
```

Notice the coefficient names. So now when you use the `predict` function it expects variables called
`Iris[,1]`, ... etc to be in `newdata`, which this is not the case, so `predict` will ignore the newdata.

As for the `~ .` form: this is just a quick method to select all variables from the data (given by`data=`),
excluding those to the left-hand side of the equation (`lhs ~ rhs`), into the model.  [`See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame). Note, you can
use the data argument to only select certain columns.

So the first `lda` function call above is equivalent to writing all the names out manually

```
z <- lda(Sp ~ Sepal.L. + Sepal.W. + Petal.L. + Petal.W.  , 
                             Iris, prior = c(1,1,1)/3, subset = train)
```

Note it is common to most (all??) of the predict methods, that the names in any new data will need to match those from the model