# Excluding variables when extracting the model frame from a formula in R

Tags: r

I'm using `model.frame()` in R (to use within a function) but I can't manage to exclude some of the variables with the formula by using `-`.
For example, in a data frame (data) with variables "y", "x1", "x2" and "x3", by using:

```
model.frame(y ~ . - x3, data)
```

I would get a data frame including all "y", "x1", "x2" and "x3".

Is there a way to exclude "x3" using a formula and not removing the variable directly as in:`data[,-4]`?

Comment: Assume that you are not looking for y ~ x1 + x2 ?

Comment: Relevant (though it doesn't answer this question) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't figure out how to do this super cleanly, but you can do it in a couple of steps:

```
# example data
data <- data.frame(y=0,x1=1,x2=2,x3=3)
```

Get the full expanded formula in the context of `data` and then remove `x3`:

```
mf <- model.frame(y ~ ., data, subset=FALSE)
#formula(mf)
##y ~ x1 + x2 + x3
model.frame(update(formula(mf), ~ . -x3), data=data)
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be considered more "cleanly": `model.frame(formula(terms(y ~ . - x3, data = data, simplify = TRUE)), data)`