# Succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame with np package

Tags: r, dataframe, lm, np

This is related to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252958/9642493).

I want to succinctly write a formula with many variables to estimate a non-parametric model, and I used the method provided by the post above. However, I found it does not work with `np::npplregbw`.

As a start, the formula in linear model works well

```r
df<-data.frame(y=rnorm(10),x1=rnorm(10),x2=rnorm(10),x3=rnorm(10),x4=rnorm(10),
               x5=rnorm(10))

## Create a formula for a model with a large number of variables:
xnam <- paste("x", 1:4, sep="")
fmla <- as.formula(paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+")))

## This works
m <- lm(formula = fmla, data=df)
```

However, if we continue from the code above, and try to get a formula that is suitable for `np:npplregbw`

```r
xnam2 <- paste("y ~ ", paste(xnam, collapse= "+"))
fmla <- as.formula(paste(xnam2, '|x5'))

## This returns an error
bw <- np::npplregbw(formula = fmla, data=df)
```

This returns an error "Error in npplregbw.formula(fmla, data = df) :
invoked with improper formula, please see npplregbw documentation for proper use"

But the formula itself should work, as is seen below

```
print(fmla) ## Gets y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | x5

## This also works
bw <- np::npplregbw(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 | x5, data=df)
```

Can someone explain why this happens and how to solve this?

Comment: `eval(bquote(np::npplregbw(formula = .(fmla), data=df)))`

Comment: (This is probably a scoping issue. As you (should) know, formulas have an associated environment.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error comes from improper use of `matchc.call` npplregbw.formula`, invoked by` npplregbw`. The error is thrown in the first couple lines of code

```
npplregbw.formula <- function (formula, data, subset, na.action, call, ...) 
{
  mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  m <- match(c("formula", "data", "subset", "na.action"), 
    names(mf), nomatch = 0)
  mf <- mf[c(1, m)]
  if (!missing(call) && is.call(call)) {
    for (i in 1:length(call)) {
      if (tryCatch(class(eval(call[[i]])) == "formula", 
        error = function(e) FALSE)) 
        break
    }
    mf[[2]] <- call[[i]]
  }
  mf.xf <- mf
  mf[[1]] <- as.name("model.frame")
  mf.xf[[1]] <- as.name("model.frame")
  chromoly <- explodePipe(mf[["formula"]])
  if (length(chromoly) != 3) 
    stop("invoked with improper formula, please see npplregbw documentation for proper use")
  ...
}
```

Note a small example:

```
foo <- function(formula){
  mf <- match.call(expand.dots = FALSE)
  mf[["formula"]]
}
foo(fmla)
fmla # <=== output line
```

This is definitely something to report as an issue ([opened here](https://github.com/JeffreyRacine/R-Package-np/issues/26#issue-851227928)). The quick-fix is the one given by Roland in the comments

```
eval(bquote(np::npplregbw(formula = .(fmla), data=df)))
```

The better fix has to be done on the package end.