# Is there a shorter way to write many similar variables in lm() formula?

Tags: r, lm

I do have a huge data set and want to do some regression analysis.

This is the data set.

```
#            Winst Item1 Item2 Item3 Item4 Item5  ...  Item100
# Event1 992.19788    92    91    79    36    71  ...       93
# Event2  43.43687    62    16    58    51    30  ...       71
# Event3 219.52095   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  ...      NaN
# Event4 874.76596    89    69    82    65    56  ...       91
# Event5 602.40975    36    37    27    94    54  ...       52
```

how can I write the following code shorter?

```
lm(Winst ~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3 + Item4 + ... + Item50, data=data1)
```

In maths we use the sigma sign, but here in r this word has another meaning. Neither the `sum()` would work.

What are the options?

### Data

```
data1 <- structure(list(Winst = c(992.197884479538, 43.4368695132434, 
219.520953251049, 874.765956075862, 602.409749291837), Item1 = c(92, 
62, NaN, 89, 36), Item2 = c(91, 16, NaN, 69, 37), Item3 = c(79, 
58, NaN, 82, 27), Item4 = c(36, 51, NaN, 65, 94), Item5 = c(71, 
30, NaN, 56, 54), Item6 = c(23, 35, NaN, 67, 59), Item7 = c(44, 
64, NaN, 9, 98), Item8 = c(70, 79, NaN, 75, 57), Item9 = c(91, 
26, NaN, 76, 29), Item10 = c(99, 74, NaN, 70, 78), Item11 = c(27, 
72, NaN, 74, 16), Item12 = c(10, 48, NaN, 2, 60), Item13 = c(54, 
95, NaN, 10, 17), Item14 = c(58, 82, NaN, 83, 61), Item15 = c(21, 
88, NaN, 1, 62), Item16 = c(61, 4, NaN, 23, 8), Item17 = c(7, 
46, NaN, 18, 20), Item18 = c(67, 24, NaN, 32, 92), Item19 = c(83, 
73, NaN, 42, 41), Item20 = c(42, 65, NaN, 51, 30), Item21 = c(77, 
49, NaN, 85, 85), Item22 = c(83, 19, NaN, 71, 50), Item23 = c(25, 
42, NaN, 20, 81), Item24 = c(74, 93, NaN, 17, 58), Item25 = c(23, 
84, NaN, 64, 7), Item26 = c(22, 43, NaN, 49, 65), Item27 = c(69, 
32, NaN, 45, 42), Item28 = c(92, 20, NaN, 33, 3), Item29 = c(32, 
55, NaN, 40, 22), Item30 = c(68, 76, NaN, 38, 46), Item31 = c(28, 
91, NaN, 80, 97), Item32 = c(100, 61, NaN, 35, 91), Item33 = c(86, 
36, NaN, 63, 69), Item34 = c(54, 60, NaN, 8, 34), Item35 = c(11, 
63, NaN, 22, 53), Item36 = c(63, 80, NaN, 26, 96), Item37 = c(41, 
66, NaN, 100, 2), Item38 = c(24, 98, NaN, 24, 47), Item39 = c(82, 
31, NaN, 97, 87), Item40 = c(34, 8, NaN, 95, 32), Item41 = c(60, 
27, NaN, 14, 68), Item42 = c(48, 44, NaN, 19, 56), Item43 = c(45, 
57, NaN, 57, 40), Item44 = c(72, 75, NaN, 28, 72), Item45 = c(11, 
12, NaN, 37, 88), Item46 = c(21, 70, NaN, 15, 5), Item47 = c(46, 
22, NaN, 92, 43), Item48 = c(68, 52, NaN, 7, 48), Item49 = c(6, 
5, NaN, 16, 49), Item50 = c(93, 71, NaN, 91, 52), Item51 = c(92, 
62, NaN, 89, 36), Item52 = c(91, 16, NaN, 69, 37), Item53 = c(79, 
58, NaN, 82, 27), Item54 = c(36, 51, NaN, 65, 94), Item55 = c(71, 
30, NaN, 56, 54), Item56 = c(23, 35, NaN, 67, 59), Item57 = c(44, 
64, NaN, 9, 98), Item58 = c(70, 79, NaN, 75, 57), Item59 = c(91, 
26, NaN, 76, 29), Item60 = c(99, 74, NaN, 70, 78), Item61 = c(27, 
72, NaN, 74, 16), Item62 = c(10, 48, NaN, 2, 60), Item63 = c(54, 
95, NaN, 10, 17), Item64 = c(58, 82, NaN, 83, 61), Item65 = c(21, 
88, NaN, 1, 62), Item66 = c(61, 4, NaN, 23, 8), Item67 = c(7, 
46, NaN, 18, 20), Item68 = c(67, 24, NaN, 32, 92), Item69 = c(83, 
73, NaN, 42, 41), Item70 = c(42, 65, NaN, 51, 30), Item71 = c(77, 
49, NaN, 85, 85), Item72 = c(83, 19, NaN, 71, 50), Item73 = c(25, 
42, NaN, 20, 81), Item74 = c(74, 93, NaN, 17, 58), Item75 = c(23, 
84, NaN, 64, 7), Item76 = c(22, 43, NaN, 49, 65), Item77 = c(69, 
32, NaN, 45, 42), Item78 = c(92, 20, NaN, 33, 3), Item79 = c(32, 
55, NaN, 40, 22), Item80 = c(68, 76, NaN, 38, 46), Item81 = c(28, 
91, NaN, 80, 97), Item82 = c(100, 61, NaN, 35, 91), Item83 = c(86, 
36, NaN, 63, 69), Item84 = c(54, 60, NaN, 8, 34), Item85 = c(11, 
63, NaN, 22, 53), Item86 = c(63, 80, NaN, 26, 96), Item87 = c(41, 
66, NaN, 100, 2), Item88 = c(24, 98, NaN, 24, 47), Item89 = c(82, 
31, NaN, 97, 87), Item90 = c(34, 8, NaN, 95, 32), Item91 = c(60, 
27, NaN, 14, 68), Item92 = c(48, 44, NaN, 19, 56), Item93 = c(45, 
57, NaN, 57, 40), Item94 = c(72, 75, NaN, 28, 72), Item95 = c(11, 
12, NaN, 37, 88), Item96 = c(21, 70, NaN, 15, 5), Item97 = c(46, 
22, NaN, 92, 43), Item98 = c(68, 52, NaN, 7, 48), Item99 = c(6, 
5, NaN, 16, 49), Item100 = c(93, 71, NaN, 91, 52)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Event1", 
"Event2", "Event3", "Event4", "Event5"))
```

Comment: `lm(Winst ~ ., data1)` - used this way `.` means all terms remaining in the data.

Comment: Please use `dput` rather than sharing extensive code to generate data as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). This time I've helped you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame)

Comment: Thank you for you help jav.sf!

Answer (score 4):

You could use `reformulate` and `grep` the terms from column names with regular expressions.

```
fo <- reformulate(grep('^Item([1-9]|[1-4][0-9]|50)$', names(data1), value=TRUE), 
                  'Winst')
fo
# Winst ~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3 + Item4 + Item5 + Item6 + Item7 + 
#   Item8 + Item9 + Item10 + Item11 + Item12 + Item13 + Item14 + 
#   Item15 + Item16 + Item17 + Item18 + Item19 + Item20 + Item21 + 
#   Item22 + Item23 + Item24 + Item25 + Item26 + Item27 + Item28 + 
#   Item29 + Item30 + Item31 + Item32 + Item33 + Item34 + Item35 + 
#   Item36 + Item37 + Item38 + Item39 + Item40 + Item41 + Item42 + 
#   Item43 + Item44 + Item45 + Item46 + Item47 + Item48 + Item49 + 
#   Item50
```

See demo [there](https://regex101.com/r/OjH5Bv/1).

And then just

```
lm(fo, data1)
```

or

```
do.call('lm', list(fo, quote(data1)))
```

to display the "Call:" right.

Answer (score 3):

My take on this issue:

```
items <- paste0("Item", 1:50)

model <- formula(paste("Winst ~", paste0(items, collapse = "+")))

model
```

```
Winst ~ Item1 + Item2 + Item3 + Item4 + Item5 + Item6 + Item7 +
    Item8 + Item9 + Item10 + Item11 + Item12 + Item13 + Item14 +
    Item15 + Item16 + Item17 + Item18 + Item19 + Item20 + Item21 +
    Item22 + Item23 + Item24 + Item25 + Item26 + Item27 + Item28 +
    Item29 + Item30 + Item31 + Item32 + Item33 + Item34 + Item35 +
    Item36 + Item37 + Item38 + Item39 + Item40 + Item41 + Item42 +
    Item43 + Item44 + Item45 + Item46 + Item47 + Item48 + Item49 +
    Item50
```

Then, you just call the model from `lm()`

```
lm(model, data = data1)
```