# svyglm - how to code for a logistic regression model across all variables?

Tags: r, logistic-regression, survey, weighted

In R using GLM to include all variables you can simply use a . as shown [How to succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame)

for example:

```
y <- c(1,4,6)
d <- data.frame(y = y, x1 = c(4,-1,3), x2 = c(3,9,8), x3 = c(4,-4,-2))
mod <- lm(y ~ ., data = d)
```

however I am struggling to do this with svydesign. I have many exploratory variables and an ID and weight variable, so first I create my survey design:

```
des <-svydesign(ids=~id, weights=~wt, data = df)
```

Then I try creating my binomial model using weights:

```
binom <- svyglm(y~.,design = des, family="binomial")
```

But I get the error:

```
Error in svyglm.survey.design(y ~ ., design = des, family = "binomial") : 
  all variables must be in design = argument
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I can tell from the source of the `svyglm.survey.design` method, using `.` in place of all other variables in the data set is not supported here

Comment: Is the only alternative to then enter them manually?

Comment: If your concern is copy and pasting, you can also construct formulas from strings

Answer (score 2):

You typically wouldn't want to do this, because "all the variables" would include design metadata such as weights, cluster indicators, stratum indicators, etc

You can use `col.names` to extract all the variable names from a design object and then `reformulate`, probably after subsetting the names, eg with the `api` example in the package

```
> all_the_names <- colnames(dclus1)
> all_the_actual_variables <- all_the_names[c(2, 11:37)]
> reformulate(all_the_actual_variables,"y")
y ~ stype + pcttest + api00 + api99 + target + growth + sch.wide + 
    comp.imp + both + awards + meals + ell + yr.rnd + mobility + 
    acs.k3 + acs.46 + acs.core + pct.resp + not.hsg + hsg + some.col + 
    col.grad + grad.sch + avg.ed + full + emer + enroll + api.stu
```

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why it wasn't possible. Thank you also for your work in producing and maintaining the package.