# Linear Regression in R with variable number of explanatory variables

Tags: r, linear-regression, glm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Specifying formula in R with glm without explicit declaration of each covariate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588961/specifying-formula-in-r-with-glm-without-explicit-declaration-of-each-covariate)
>   [how to succinctly write a formula with many variables from a data frame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5251507/how-to-succinctly-write-a-formula-with-many-variables-from-a-data-frame)

I have a vector of Y values and a matrix of X values that I want to perform a multiple regression on (i.e. Y = X[column 1] + X[column 2] + ... X[column N])

The problem is that the number of columns in my matrix (N) is not prespecified. I know in R, to perform a linear regression you have to specify the equation:

```
fit = lm(Y~X[,1]+X[,2]+X[,3])
```

But how do I do this if I don't know how many columns are in my X matrix?

Thanks!

Comment: I was able to find several questions similar to yours by searching for `[r] formula`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Three ways, in increasing level of flexibility.

**Method 1**

Run your regression using the formula notation:

```
fit <- lm( Y ~ . , data=dat )
```

**Method 2**

Put all your data in one data.frame, not two:

```
dat <- cbind(data.frame(Y=Y),as.data.frame(X))
```

Then run your regression using the formula notation:

```
fit <- lm( Y~. , data=dat )
```

**Method 3**

Another way is to build the formula yourself:

```
model1.form.text <- paste("Y ~",paste(xvars,collapse=" + "),collapse=" ")
model1.form <- as.formula( model1.form.text )
model1 <- lm( model1.form, data=dat )
```

In this example, xvars is a character vector containing the names of the variables you want to use.